# Is Realm for Swift save against injection attacks?

Tags: swift, security, realm

Is it save to send user input directly into the realm, especially when using the .filter method with its string like syntax (e.g. `.filter("name == '\(user.name)'` where `user.name` is a value provided via a text box)? Is there a possibility of injection attacks, like in traditional sql databases or does realm uses input sanitisation to prevent the execution of malicious inputs?

Comment: Are you asking about [MongoDB Realm Security](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/security/)? I am sure there's some documentation that covers it... somewhere ;-)

Comment: Yes exactly, but I can not find anything about injection attacks. I'm coming from sql databases and MongoDB Realm is my first try with nosql databases.

Comment: Well, an injection attack includes a pretty broad range of attack vectors and Realm can be an offline or sync'd database and... there are a bunch of other variables too expansive to be covered here on SO. If you're asking specifically about SQL Injection attack, that kind of attack would not have relevance against a NoSQL database. I think a better use of your time would be to work with Realm a bit and get comfortable with the platform.

Comment: This does allow an injection attack. If your user.name parameter contains a text like "***dummy' OR 1==1***", all data will be returned, because the filter text is "name == 'dummy' OR 1==1". This is because when realm receives the filter text, it has already been replaced by the compiler. You need to make sure that no ' is inside the user.name at least.